# Mixed-effects model for a strongly unbalanced design

Tags: r, mixed-model, unbalanced-classes

I am somehow unsure on the best option to analyze these data.
Here is my study case:

The response variable is a morphometric measure, one for each individual.

During 10 years, say 2000-2009, people went to the field to collect data (the response variable) during two specific months (always the same along the study period) on a variable number of occasions. For instance, in 2000 data came from three surveys made on days 4, 40, and 56, in 2001 data came from two surveys made on days 10 and 49, in 2002 data came from four surveys made on days 2, 34, 45, and 60, and so on. Day number is equal to 1 when made the first day of the specific two-months interval and it is equal to 60 when made the last day of that two-months interval. The number of observations (measures from individuals) is not the same for each survey but an individual is never sampled twice. Also, for each year I have a unique value of three environmental variables - I am interested in seeing if these interact with my response variable.

Thus, my predictors are on one hand, the day from which measures came, and on the other the environmental variables.

As you can see, the study is quite unbalanced.

I would attempt to analyze these data by using a mixed-effects model where the response variable depends on the day plus the three environmental variables and the random factor would be survey (numbered from 1 for the first survey in 2000 and, say, 49 for the last survey in 2009) nested under year. In `R` the `nlme` code is:

```
mixmod <- lme(morph ~ poly(day) + env1 + env2 + env3, random=~1|year/survey, data=data)
```

Where `poly(day)` tests for the linear and quadratic effect of `day` and where `env1`, `env2`, and `env3` are the environmental variables, and the random structure refers to survey number nested to year. I have checked the normality and homoskedasticity of residuals.

I would really appreciate any commentary and suggestion on this.

Comment: Does it seem a reasonable approach?